# Hide/Show menu in Navbar - blazor

Tags: blazor

I would like one of the menus in the navbar to be shown only when "/"(index page) is active.

On load, 'Menu5' is hidden. When I select a file on 'landingpage'(which is my on load page) , I am redirected to "/" (index page) using navigator. 'Menu5' need to be shown on NavBar when I am in "/".

NavBar.razor:

```
<li class="has-dropdown" hidden="@hideMenu">
       <a href="#.html">Menu5</a>

@code {
   public bool hideMenu= true;
}
```

landingpage.Razor:

```
 @code{
         public bool hideMenu= true; 
 }

private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
      hideMenu= true;
      UriHelper.NavigateTo("/");

}
```

index.razor:

```
    public bool hideMenu= false; 

    [JSInvokable]
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        hideMenu= false;      // this line does not seem to work    
    }
```

Edited code:

My onload page is "landingpage". When I am on "landingpage", page2 and page3 menu should be hidden.

Second and third menu item need to be shown, when I navigate to 'Index' page ("/") on file selection thru code(UriHelper.NavigateTo) from 'landingpage'. Thank you.

Navbar.razor:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <!-- first menu item-->
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="landingpage">Landing Page</a></li>

       
        <!-- second menu item-->
        @if (routeData.PageType != typeof(Landingpage))
        {
            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#.html">page 2</a>  // its route path would be "/"
             </li>
         }

        <!-- third menu item -->
        @if (routeData.PageType != typeof(Landingpage))
        {
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#.html">page 3</a>  
        </li>
        }
 
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can't build a minimum working example based on your code snippets here's code based on the standard Blazor Template that demonstrates how to turn off items in the `NavMenu` based on which page you are on.  You should be able to adapt this code to fit your specific situation.

First we cascade the `RouteData` instance in `App.razor`.  `RouteData.PageType` is the class type for the component that represents the current route.  For example for "/" this will be `Index`.

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue TValue="RouteData" value="@routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Net5.0 version looks like this:

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue TValue="RouteData" value="@routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </CascadingValue>

    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

We can now use the cascading parameter in `NavMenu` to toggle menu items.

```
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">SO73610751</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        @if(routeData.PageType != typeof(FetchData))
        {
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                    <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                </NavLink>
            </div>
        }
        @if (routeData.PageType != typeof(Counter))
        {
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        }
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    [CascadingParameter] private RouteData routeData { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (routeData is null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("No Cascaded RouteData - You must cascade RouteData in App");
    }

    private string? NavMenuCssClass 
    => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

Here's the view on `Counter`.  Note `FetchData` is hidden.

[image]

And:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful. I have incorporated code as above but couldn't get it to work. May I know if I am properly using routeData.PageType in navMenu. Please see the edited code section.

Comment: It looks right.  If you're having problems get my version working in a default server template first to make sure you have everything right.

Comment: I am rite now using web assembly. Does it work on web assembly?

Comment: It will work in both.  Here's a temporary Github repo - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO73613087-WASM - with the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the repo. My target framework  is net5.0.  When I add this line (<FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />), It says "Found markupelement with unexpected name FocusOnNavigate or add using directive.. ". I ignored this line last time since showing error. May thats why it is not working. Do we have any other option if this cant be used for my target framework?

Comment: [Polite] Why are you using Net5.0.  It's obselete - out of support?  I've updated the answer and added a Net5.0 WASM project set to the repo which works.

Comment: NP - happy coding.